# Access API from another host

Tags: iri-node, ports

I run my IOTA node inside a VPC, behind a firewall;

I would like to be able to access the API from another host then localhost, but that is where IRI has bound:

```
$ cat bin/iota.ini | grep PORT
PORT = 14700

$ netstat -ln | grep 14700
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:14700         :::*                    LISTEN
```

How can I make IRI bind to all IPs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if you use a .ini config file, you can also add this to it

```
API_HOST = 0.0.0.0
```

Comment: Marking this as the correct answer, is it is what I ended up using.

Answer (score 6):

You have to start IRI using the --remote flag. and don't forget to disable some API calls. For example:

```
java -jar iri.jar -p 14700 -r 14700 -n "udp://neighbor1:14265" --remote-limit-api "removeNeighbors, addNeighbors, interruptAttachingToTangle, attachToTangle, getNeighbors" --remote
```

See [here](https://iotasupport.com/startup-flags.shtml) for other IRI startup flags